# Python ZipFile - ValueError: I/O operation on closed file

Tags: python

When I use the zipfile object in multiple functions, it works fine. However, when I try to run the one of the functions in thread, it gives the error "I/O operation on closed file".

Below code works fine which validates and extracts the zipfile

```
from zipfile import ZipFile
from threading import Thread
```

```
    def extract_data(file):
        zip_file = Zipfile(file)
        validate = validate_function(zip_file)
        if validate.status_code == 200:
                data = extract_function(zip_file)
```

However, If I run the extract_function in thread, It gives me "ValueError: I/O operation on closed file"

```
    def extract_data(file):
        zip_file = Zipfile(file)
        validate = validate_function(zip_file)
        if validate.status_code == 200:
                extract = Thread(target=extract_function,args=[zip_file])
                extract.start()
```

Please guide me for understanding the root cause of this issue.

Update:

Here is the sample code to reproduce the issue:

```
from zipfile import ZipFile
from threading import Thread
import pandas as pd
from flask import Flask, request, Response
from werkzeug.middleware.proxy_fix import ProxyFix
from werkzeug.datastructures import FileStorage
from flask_restplus import Api, Resource, reqparse, cors
from flask_cors import cross_origin
```

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.wsgi_app = ProxyFix(app.wsgi_app)
```

```
api = Api(app,
          version='1.0.0',
          doc='/',
         )
```

```
def validate_function(zip_file):
        try:
            error = ZipFile.testzip(zip_file)
            if error is None:
                return Response('Zip file is validated',200)
            else:
                return Response('Invalid Zip file',601)
        
        except Exception as e:
            return Response('Error :' + str(e),601)
```

```
def extract_function(zip_file):
    df_list = []
    try:
        for file in zip_file.namelist():
            if file.endswith('.csv'):
                df_list.append(pd.read_csv(zip_file.open(file)))
            else:
                excel_df = pd.read_excel(zipfile.open(file),None)
                if type(excel_df) == dict:
                    df_list.extend(list(excel_df.values()))
                else:
                    df_list.append(excel_df)
        print(len(df_list))
    except Exception as e:
        print('Error in converting to dataframe', str(e))
```

```
def extract_data(file):
        zip_file = ZipFile(file)
        resp = validate_function(zip_file)
        if resp.status_code == 200:
            data = Thread(target= extract_function, args=[zip_file])
            data.start()
            #extract_function(zip_file) --> This works
        return resp
```

```
process_data = reqparse.RequestParser()
process_data.add_argument('file', location='files', type=FileStorage, required=True, help='Input file in Zip format')
@api.route('/process-data')
@api.expect(process_data)
class DataExtract(Resource):
    @cors.crossdomain(origin='*')
    @cross_origin()
    def post(self):
        file = request.files['file']

        resp =  extract_data(file)
            
        return resp
```

```
app.run()
```

Comment: where is extract_function? is it custom or built in?

Comment: @ZainUlAbidin extract_function is the custom function. Would you like to have a look on the extract function? Please let me know. I will update the question with extract_function

Comment: for sure . i would like to .

Comment: Please create a [mre]. I guess the problem is not in the code you posted but in the part you didn't post. Also note that the process of creating a MRE is "the guide for understanding the root cause of the issue". You'll likely be able to find the problem yourself if you follow this, but if not, you'll end up with a good question for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @MadhavanSalai - What does `validate_function()` do?

Comment: @PaulP, a [mre] would avoid all these questions...

Comment: Thanks all for your time. I have updated the question with sample code to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use [with](https://thispointer.com/python-open-a-file-using-open-with-statement-benefits-explained-with-examples/) to open files, so they are closed correctly after you are done. You also have to open the file separately in the new thread:

```
def extract_data(file):
    with ZipFile(file) as zip_file:
        validate = validate_function(zip_file)

    if validate.status_code == 200:
            extract = Thread(target=extract_function,args=[file])
            extract.start()

def extract_function(file):
    with ZipFile(file) as zip_file:
        # extract ...
```

Comment: When I tried this, I am getting "ValueError: seek of closed file" error at "with ZipFile(file) as zip_file" line in extract_function